How can I get back old context menu for Windows 11 right click? Tried 4 different methods and none seem to work
Windows 11 version is 23H2 22631.4037.

Tried adding reg add exe command from Microsoft.com
Tried Winaero Tweaker.
Tried PowerShell.
Tried adding manually by typing.

None of the the methods above is enabling old right click menu on Windows 11.
I can see the registry is being added into registries and I have tried several reboots, killing and re-enabling explorer.exe from task manager, still showing windows 11 current right click menu and not the old right click menu.
Verified and its there in registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\CLSID
{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2} 
InprocServer32
empty value field


You cannot; The old context menu was removed from Windows 11. If you need the old context menu the only option today is to downgrade to Windows 10 22H2. Windows 10 support ends in 2025.

must be a new windows update because couple months ago, i was able to get it in windows11 by the same registry setting above.

Hold shift + right-click to open the classic context menu in Windows 11.
